# Annulus of convergence for laurent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, laurent-series

I have the Laurent series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n! z^n}{n^n} +  \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n/z^n $$

and want to determine the annulus of convergence. The second sum clearly converges when |z|>2, but I can't quite get where the first one converges. Wolfram Alpha claims it converges on |z| < e by Ratio test but I don't see how they got this, I get L=1 (indeterminant result) when using ratio test.

If these are the two correct numbers, is the annulus of convergence then 2<|z|< e?

Comment: Hint: you could use the ratio criterion to determine the radius of convergence, or the root one. It might be useful to use the Stirling approximation: $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ (By the way, it seems you have missed a $<e$ on the region of convergence wolfram gives you)

Comment: Shouldn’t be necessary to go to something as recondite as Stirling, @GabrieleCassese. The requisite limit often comes up in elementary Calculus classes.

Comment: @Lubin It is not necessary, it might be useful